# Image cropping with arbitrary shape

Tags: php, javascript, image, image-processing, canvas

I need to crop an image with any arbitrary shape rather than using square or oval shape. Is it possible in php or javascript ? I've tries some JS libraries but failed to get the exact outcome that I expected. Please share your ideas, thoughts and references with me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203160/php-gd-use-one-image-to-mask-another-image-including-transparency) with an arbitrary image mask.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to achieve something like this.http://www140.lunapic.com/editor/?action=crop&tool=wand