# How to cut a part of the image and paste it to another using PHP?

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, gd

I am building a simple image generator using PHP for a backend and I want to acchieve this feature:
- cut oval part of the source image 
- resize and paste it to certain coordinates on a destination image
- save destination image

Check out this image for example:

[image: example photo]

I am looking for a function that would manage this kind of task by taking x,y,width & height of this selection as input arguments. The solution can use imagemagick or GD (or anything else - it just has to be done using PHP).

Thank you for any help or at least to point me into the right direction!

Comment: [imagecopyresized](http://php.net/imagecopyresized) does this kind of thing.

Comment: @jocely: not for non-rectangular copies.

Comment: @MarcB thanx for this hint.. will try to make something out of it, it's a good start